# Gmail in Android - Getting No provider for gimaps

Tags: java, android, gmail-imap, gmail-api

I am using latest jars 1.5.3 from https://java.net/projects/javamail/lists/users/archive/2012-08/message/0 in android

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "gimaps");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

GmailSSLStore store = (GmailSSLStore) session.getStore("gimaps"); 
store.connect("-SNIP-@gmail.com", "-SNIP-");
```

and this error in last line "No provider for gimaps"

Comment: What do you want to do? Send an email directly from the phone without user intervention? Send an email using the user's google account(s)? If it's the second, better check the mail intents - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html - There are constants for Email usage

Comment: just want to get last 15 days emails from gmails with threadIds

Comment: Maybe you don't need access to gmail-specific features? Try a generic SMTP clients instead

Comment: I have tried generic providers like "imap". working fine but i couldn't get the email thread

Comment: Maybe you need to add another jar to the project?

Comment: Try the Gmail API to get a list of threads:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list

Help with auth here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html